# Laravel, merge two queries in one

Tags: php, laravel

How could I do a better code than this one:

```
$data1 = UploadsPois::where('estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA)
    ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();

foreach ($data1 as $carga) {
    $carga->UserResponsable = User::findOrFail($carga->responsable);
    $carga->Pois            = Pois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $carga->Log = LogsPois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)
        ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->first();
}
$tareas['data1'] = $data1;

// All this bucle takes ~13000 miliseconds

$data2 = UploadsPois::where('estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_DEVUELTA_REVISION)
    ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
    ->where('revisado_por', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();

foreach ($data2 as $carga) {
    $carga->UserResponsable = User::findOrFail($carga->responsable);
    $carga->UserValidador   = User::findOrFail($carga->validado_por);
    $carga->Pois            = Pois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $carga->Log             = LogsPois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)
        ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->first();
}
$tareas['data2'] = $data2;

// And this one takes ~ 20 or 50 miliseconds
```

Those bucles are pretty the same, how could I merge in one single foreach and 1 single call to `UploadsPois` model?
I'm not sure how could I set `$tareas['data1']` and `$tareas['data2']` in the same process.

Comment: You're doing 3 additional queries in a `foreach()` loop... If you've got everything setup correctly, `$carga->UserResponable`, `$carga->Pois` and `$carga->Log` could all be relationships, and you could simply call `UploadsPois::with(["UserResponable", "Pois", "Log"])` and skip the foreach entirely. Honestly though, that's a little too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: @TimLewis In`UploadPois` model I have this relation: `public function User(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\User');}` then should I add a `UserResponsable` too that belongs tu App\User as well?

Comment: Yup; why not? You're essentially doing that the long way in the loop, `findOrFail($carga->responsable)`, but the catch is that if it's a relationship, you can eager load it to speed up queries.

Comment: Trying to figure it out to do those relations, thanks mate.

Comment: All relationships in Laravel take additional parameters for specifying table name and columns, so anywhere you're using `$carga->whatever`, you're replace with `$this->whatever` in `UploadsPois` model. `$schema_country` would have to be replaced with `$this->schema_country`, but aside from that, there shouldn't be anything weird about em.

Comment: Coudl you give an example for `UploadsPois::with(["UserResponable")->where(etc)`. I'm trying to at least use that as a relation. As I said before, I put a `public function UserResponable() { return $this->hasOne('App\User'); }` in UploadPois model and `public function UserResponable() { return $this->hasOne('App\UploadsPois'); }` in User model, but I don't get how to pass the parameter `$carga->responsable` that I use to set  `$carga->UserResponsable` in my `foreach`

Comment: `return $this->hasOne('App\User', $this->responsable);` Like I said, anywhere you use `$carga`, you switch with `$this` in the model. If you don't pass a second parameter, it's going to look for `user_id` column (Model name you're relating to + `"_id"`). Also, you wouldn't name both functions `UserResponable()`, the inverse would be `Pois()`. Also also, function names are `camelCase`, so `userResponable()`, etc.

Comment: I'm ok with `$carga->UserResponsable` can be changed with the relation `UserResponsable() {return $this->belongsTo('App\User', $this->responsable);` I'm there just passing 1 parameter for a simple query, but for the other `$carga->Pois` and `$carga->Log` I'm using the models Pois and LogsPois with many where, whereNull, order, etc. How can set up those queries using relations? pretty confused. In the past I have used models but for simple acces to other models properties, not querying them like in my case inside the foreach

Comment: The answer below demonstrates how you can query with those additional params at runtime, but you can use `->where()`, `->whereNull()` etc in relationship queries without issue. `Util::POIS_INGRESADO` is global, so you can use that in the model, and `$schema_country` will match `$this->schema_country` (since the initial query uses `->where("schema_country", $schema_country)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this code, I can tell there are 4 important models: `UploadsPois`, `User`, `Pois`, `LogPois`.

You can set up relationships to load all this data without having to loop.

See [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships), [Eloquent Relationships: Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```php
# UploadPois model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use User;
use Pois;
use LogsPois;

class UploadsPois extends Model
{
    public function user_responsable()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'responsable');
    }

    public function user_validador()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'validado_por');
    }

    public function pois()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pois::class, 'upload_pois_id');
    }

    public function log()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LogsPois::class, 'upload_pois_id');
    }
}
```

You can also define the inverse of the relationships as follows.

```php
# User model
namespace App;

// Usually User model extends this instead of base model.
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use UploadsPois;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function responsable_uploads_pois()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UploadsPois::class, 'responsable');
    }

    public function validador_uploads_pois()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UploadsPois::class, 'validado_por');
    }
}
```

```php
# Pois model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use UploadsPois;

class Pois extends Model
{
    public function uploads_pois()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UploadsPois::class, 'upload_pois_id');
    }
}
```

```php
# LogPois model
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use UploadsPois;

class LogPois extends Model
{
    public function uploads_pois()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UploadsPois::class, 'upload_pois_id');
    }
}
```

Now that we have all relationships defined, your `$data1` variable can be obtained as follows:

```php
UploadsPois::where([
    ['estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA],
    ['schema_country', $schema_country]
])
->with([
    'user_responsable',
    'pois' => function ($pois) {
        $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO);
    },
    'log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
        $log->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
])
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

as for `$data2`:

```php
UploadsPois::where([
    ['estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_DEVUELTA_REVISION],
    ['schema_country', $schema_country],
    ['revisado_por', auth()->id()] //Same as \Auth::id(), same as \Auth::user()->id
])
->with([
    'user_responsable',
    'user_validador',
    'pois' => function ($pois) {
        $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO)
    },
    'log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
        $log->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
])
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

Laravel naming conventions dictate your relationship methods must be in snake_case.

About combining those queries. The only differences I see are the following:

- `$data1` has `estado_carga` equal to `Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA` whereas `$data2` has `estado_carga` equal to `Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_DEVUELTA_REVISION`
- `$data2` has an additional filter (`validado_por` equal to authenticated user's `id`)
- `$data2` has an additional relationship loaded (`user_validador`)

If you want really want to combine the queries, you could just not filter by those 2 conditions initially.

```php
$data = UploadsPois::where('schema_country', $schema_country)
->with([
    'user_responsable',
    'user_validador',
    'pois' => function ($pois) {
        $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO)
    },
    'log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
        $log->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    }
])
->orderBy('id', 'asc')
->get();
```

This returns a collection, which you can then filter using a variety of methods (`where`, `firstWhere`, `filter`, `reject`, etc)

```php
# data1
$data->where('estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA);
```

```php
# data2
$data->where('estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_DEVUELTA_REVISION)->where('validado_por', auth()->id());
```

See [Collections: Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#available-methods)

Comment: Thanks you very, very much (you both with @Tim Lewis. I habe a question, the blade view that receive this data expect this in a certain point: `$carga->Log->comentario` before was working, because in my foreach loop I was defining: `$carga->Log = LogsPois::wh... etc` but now its says that: `Ùndefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$Log. I thought that would be the name of the relation, I rename it as `Log` (not log as you code) but I still have the issue.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I get in both versions: https://i.imgur.com/Sau8Sjd.png

Comment: Hm, my problem was because I put a `->first()` in `'Log' => function ($log)` but how can I retrieve just the `first` element of the collection? I don't want to `get` all of them

Comment: You can put the `->first()` in `"log" => function($log){ $log->...->first(); }`, or simply do `$carga->log->first()->comentario`. But if `$carga->log->first()` returns `null`, that'll be a problem (in your screenshot, the `log` relation is an empty `Collection`, so `$carga->log->first()` is `null`.)