# Laravel, relation comes empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

(Laravel 5.3) I had a code that assign a property to a collection (`UploadsPois`), in a foreach loop. It was this one:

```
$data= UploadsPois::where('estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA)
    ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();

foreach ($data as $carga) {
    $carga->UserResponsable = User::findOrFail($carga->responsable);
    $carga->Pois            = Pois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $carga->Log = LogsPois::where('upload_pois_id', $carga->id)
        ->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
        ->whereNull('address_id')
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->first(); //  HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
}
```

That code was dumb and slow, but was working ok. My data was well retrieved (check the image below). I could use the data on my view to read it in some part like this:

```
@foreach($data as $carga)

    @if(is_object($carga->Log))
        //do something with
        $carga->Log->comentario
```

Now, with the help of @IGP and @Tim Lewis ([Laravel, merge two queries in one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58292313/3541320)) I replaced that foreach with the use of relations on my `UploadsPois` model.

`UploadsPois` mode has this relations:

```
public function UserResponsable()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'responsable');
}

public function Pois()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Pois', 'upload_pois_id');
}

public function Log()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\LogsPois', 'upload_pois_id');
}
```

And now the code on the controller is:

```
$data = UploadsPois::where([
    ['estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA],
    ['schema_country', $schema_country]
])
    ->with([
        'UserResponsable',
        'Pois' => function ($pois) {
            $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO);
        },
        'Log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
            $log->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
                ->whereNull('address_id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
                //NOW I'm not calling ti ->first(), so I get the whole collection, but when I use first I get an empty collection
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

But I have two problems now:

- First, `Log` relation is getting a collection of 3 items. The problem I think is with the `->first()` that is being omitted in the `->with([])` part.
- In my view, I can't acces to `$data->Log` anymore because now `Log`, `Pois` and `UserResponsable` aswell are not attributes, but their are relations.

Here is a screenshot of the `dd($data->first());` with the old code and the new one with relations:

[image]

Comment: Done, no more edits.

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is good compare to first one. You can do some things like,

1) Make another relationship of `hasOne()`

```
public function singleLog() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\LogsPois', 'upload_pois_id')->latest();
}
```

2) Get only first result at the time of retrieving data (at time of processing)  `// take value using hard coded like Log[0]`

3) Make scope in model

```
public function scopeGetSignleLog($query, $schema_country)
{
   return $query->where('schema_country', $schema_country)
                ->whereNull('address_id')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->first();
}
```

in Controller,

```
$data = UploadsPois::where([
          ['estado_carga', Util::UPLOAD_POIS_CARGA_INGRESADA],
          ['schema_country', $schema_country]
    ])
    ->with([
        'UserResponsable',
        'Pois' => function ($pois) {
            $pois->where('pois_validate', Util::POIS_INGRESADO);
        },
        'Log' => function ($log) use ($schema_country) {
            return $log->getSignleLog($schema_country;)
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I had a `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getSingleLog()`error (I change the name to `getSingleLog` and  `scopeGetSingleLog` in the model). I'm using Laravel 5.3 by the way.

Comment: No you should use this name with `scope`. Refer this doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes